# Koma script description environment specific font

Tags: koma-script

The font for description environment can be changed by using the `\setsansfont` in koma classes. Is there a way to be more specific, like `\addtokomafont{disposition}` is for headings?

Comment: I don't really understand. `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` are `fontspec` commands, they have nothing to do with the KOMA classes. To change the font of labels in the `description` environment, use `\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{<font commands}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry, I missed the command. Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See table 3.2 on page 55 in the English version of the KOMA-manual for a complete list of elements that can be changed with `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`.

Here you'll find

> `descriptionlabel`
>
> labels, i. e., the optional argument of `\item`
> in the description environment (see section 3.18, page 106)

So use e.g. `\addtokomafont{descriptionlabel}{...}`.